# JAVASCRIPT AWS S3 signed URL

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to upload a file using the signed URL.

Is there any way I can generate a signed URL without using the AWS-SDK?

Thanks

Update:

Hello,

let me explain myself a little bit better. I want to upload a file from the browser to Amazon S3 bucket. In order to do that, I have a webservice that generates the signed url using the followed function. 
I am using this get signature function, using Javascript.

function getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName) {

```
           var kDate= CryptoJS.HmacSHA512( dateStamp, "AWS4" + key)
           var kRegion= CryptoJS.HmacSHA512( regionName, kDate);
           var kService=CryptoJS.HmacSHA512( serviceName, kRegion);
           var kSigning= CryptoJS.HmacSHA512( "aws4_request", kService);

           return kSigning;
        }
```

The string sample I found is:
"https://s3.amazonaws.com#resource#?AWSAccessKeyId=#aws.accessID#&Expires=#expirationInSeconds#&Signature=#urlEncodedSignature#"

Is it ok?
Thanks

Comment: Use AWS CLI to generate signed URL

Comment: The logic you need to be familiar with in order to implement in your own code for signing requests without using the SDK [is fully documented](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html)... so, it isn't clear what you are asking.

Comment: I update the question with all the information i have so far. please take a look.
thanks